# fwrite() in php not working

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make a very simple 'settings' or admin zone and I want a .json file to contain some settings for my client to change in a webpage. I have a system to obtain everything, etc. But with my script It won't actually change the file. Its getting really annoying. I use a free host for now called biz.nf and was wondering if the host was just the problem

Here's my code snippet:

```html
                                <?
                                if($_POST['Submit']){
                                        $open = fopen("http://www.pingguminc.co.nf/site/settings/sellers.json","w");
                                        $text = $_POST['update'];
                                        fwrite($open, $text);
                                        fclose($open);
                                        echo "File updated.<br />"; 
                                }else{
                                        $file = file("http://www.pingguminc.co.nf/site/settings/sellers.json");
                                        echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
                                        echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"100\" rows=\"30\">";
                                        foreach($file as $text) {
                                                echo $text;
                                        } 
                                        echo "</textarea><br/>";
                                        echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
                                        </form>";
                                }
                                ?>
```

Sorry about the weird indents.

Thanks in advance. :o

(PS: I made sure the .json file AND the folder its in has the 777 permission.)

Comment: Can you use a URL as the file to write to with `fwrite`?

Comment: Ooh. I don't know I couldn't? I will try that.

Comment: Can you do `phpinfo();` and see if allow_url_fopen is 1? Many shared hosts have this option disabled for safety reasons. If this is disabled fopen won't work. Is www.pingguminc.co.nf the hostname of your website? Then you can solve the problem by just opening the file locally instead of adding the URL. And indeed fwrite will not change the contents of the remote file - even if you're provider allows you to pick it up..

Comment: Even if you can open a remote file for reading with `fopen` you can't write to it. The file has to be on your local file system to write, and you have to open it that way (not using the url).